# Qt disable touch screen detection

Tags: c++, qt, touchscreen

Is there a way to configure a Qt application to not detect the touch screen to keep the behavior of a normal screen?

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference, or actual behavior you want to change/disable? And what hardware (device type and display and OS)? Because normally an application does not detect touch screen... It just gets what OS gives it.

Comment: Why would you do it? What is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your operating system differentiates between touch events and mouse presses, you could create a touchEvent filter to ignore the events like so:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTouchEvent> // to get rid of "error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QEvent'"

class QTouchEventFilter: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    QTouchEventFilter(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
    }

protected:

    bool eventFilter(QObject * p_obj, QEvent * p_event)
    {
        if (p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin ||
             p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchUpdate ||
             p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchEnd ||
             p_event->type() == QEvent::TouchCancel)
        {
            p_event->ignore();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Then install it on the widget you want to ignore the touch events:

```
myWidget->installEventFilter(new QTouchEventFilter);
```

However, my instinct is that on most OS's the 'touches' you're talking about are going to come in as mouse press events, and you won't be able to filter them out unless you are willing to give up all mouse input for that widget. If you are willing, use the same concept but replace the QEvent's with the once associated with the mouse.